# How can I hide my ajax action link after it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net mvc 3. I have  this code on my view.

```
                   <%
                  foreach(Team t in Model.AvailableTeams.AvailableTeams)
                    { %>
                     <%= Ajax.ActionLink(t.Title
                    , "InviteTeamToChallenge"
                    , "Challenge"
                    , new{id = t.TeamId
                    , challengeId = Model.ChallengeId
                    , teamId = t.TeamId
                    , invitedByUserId = Model.userId}
                    , new AjaxOptions
                     {
                          OnSuccess = "hideLabel(teamId)"       
                     } ) %>
                    <% } %>
```

i am trying to pass the teamId in anyway possible to a javascript function that can then hide the action link after it has been clicked. Right now, the javascript method is not getting called. here is my javascript:

```
      function hideLabel(teamId) {
          alert("in JS");
          alert(teamId);
          $('.teamId').hide();
       }
```

I would also like to refresh a partial view on the page that lists teams that have been selected, but that is another problem to deal with after i get this piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set unique id for each action link:

```
new AjaxOptions
                     {
                          OnSuccess = "hideLabel(" + t.TeamId + ")"       
                     },
new { id="actionLink" + t.TeamId  )
```

and than

```
function hideLabel(teamId) {
          $('#actionLink' + teamId).hide();
       }
```

Comment: that got the method to get called, but it still does not hide the action link. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing:

`OnSuccess = "hideLabel(" + t.TeamId + ")"`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
OnBegin="javascript:this.style.display='none'"
or 
OnComplete="javascript:this.style.display='none'"
```

e.g.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Hide button before ajax", "myAction", new AjaxOptions { OnBegin="javascript:this.style.display='none'" })
```

or

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Hide button after ajax", "myAction", new AjaxOptions { OnComplete="javascript:this.style.display='none'" })
```